# display getCertifcation if a song has getCertification

Tags: c#

I need to display certication for a song if it has certification(silver, gold, platinum) currently i'm calling the method but that doesn't check if the song actually has a certification.

How would I then also display the 'total no of copies sold' and 'avg no of copies sold' of those songs that details have been displayed. I understand that it will require making copiesSold available to the client code but how would I go about it.

```
namespace Songs
{
    class Song
    {
        string name;
        string artist;
        int copiesSold;

        public Song(string name, string artist, int copiesSold)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.artist = artist;
            this.copiesSold = copiesSold;
        }

        public Song() : this("my_name", "my_artist", 1000)
        {

        }

        public string GetArtist()
        {
            return artist;
        }

        public string GetDetails()
        {
            return $"Name: {name} Artist: {artist} Copies Sold: {copiesSold},";
        }

        public string GetCertification()
        {
            return copiesSold < 200000 ? null : copiesSold < 400000 ? "Silver" : copiesSold < 600000 ? "Gold" : "Platinum";
        }

        public void AddCopiesSold(int number)
        {
            copiesSold += number;
        }
    }
}
```

program class

```
namespace Songs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //InputSongDetails();
            //Console.WriteLine(InputSongDetails());

            Song[] songs = new Song[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < songs.Length; i++)
            {
                songs[i] = InputSongDetails();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter an artist name, or just press return for all artists");
            var name = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            name = name.Trim();

            foreach (var song in songs)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || song.GetArtist().Equals(name))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(song.GetDetails());
                    song.GetCertification();
                }
            }

        }


        static Song InputSongDetails()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your song");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What is the artists name");
            string artist = Console.ReadLine();

            int records;
            Console.WriteLine("How many records did it sell");
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out records) || records < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is not valid please enter a number");
            }
            return new Song(name, artist, records);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of questions about `Songs` today!

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?  What isn't behaving the way you'd like, or what errors are you receiving?  You've given us a wall of code but not much in the way of what you've tried or what of those tries didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

"I need to display certication for a song if it has certification(silver, gold, platinum) currently i'm calling the method but that doesn't check if the song actually has a certification."

```
foreach (var song in songs)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || song.GetArtist().Equals(name))
    {
          Console.WriteLine(song.GetDetails());
          song.GetCertification() != null ? song.GetCertification() : /* Handle no certificate here */;
    }
}
```

For the other "questions" you have - you have to structure that clearer, it seems like you want us to write you that functionality. Stackoverflow is not a codewriting service, but this will solve your null-error (that you set `copiesSold < 200000` to).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some code. This should evaluate the artist passed in and then retrieve the songs by artist, returning the unique instance of the song.

```
song.GetArtist().Equals(name)
```

I don't see GetArtist() defined and it should take in the artist's name as a param (I would think).

Also, you redefined *name* from the song to the Artist:

```
    Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your song");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
```

...

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an artist name, or just press return for all artists");
    var name = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    name = name.Trim();
```

You should use *unique* variables (e.g.: artistName, songName, etc.) to prevent unintended collision[s] like this.